# How do I succeed setting sublime text 3 as a default text editor on Yosemite?

Tags: macos, text-editor, defaults, sublimetext

It's a matter of principle for me as I'm struggling with it for a long time. I had this issue back on Mavericks and now on Yosemite 10.10.5. 

What I'm trying to do is to set Sublime text 3 as a default text editor for all plain text files (my target were files with . and without extension, e.g .bashrc).

Here is an extract of ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist after I used this [Replace Text Edit as the default text editor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123833/replace-text-edit-as-the-default-text-editor) advice:

```
{
    LSHandlers =     (
                {
            LSHandlerContentType = "public.plain-text";
            LSHandlerRoleAll = "com.sublimetext.3";
        }
    );
}
```

In Finder when I press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> on e.g .gitconfig file it still opens with TextEdit.
 Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the comments in the cited answer and already performed a dual reboot?

Comment: What about simply selecting a file of the type you want to change, and do a Get Info, In that window, you can choose a preferred app for the file and also select Use this app to open all such files. I find that choice holds, even in Yosemite.

Comment: Doesn't work through Get Info on file as files doesn't have an extension, multiple reboots didn't work either. But made it with this **duti** answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123954/140831

Answer (score -1):

The best results with setting default applications I have achieved with a little tool called **[RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/)**.

It installs as a preference pane in System Preferences. Open **System Preferences > Default Apps** and change all the applicable extensions and/or UTIs to Sublime Text.

Comment: How do you set if the extension or UTI is not known? This is the question

Comment: RCDefaultApp hasn't been updated since 2009. That's generally not a good sign.

Comment: Thanks Arthur. Any ideas what the reason for the downvote was? (And its a shame this problem is so widespread yet Apple has refused to fix it. I know for certain they know about it because I filled a RADAR on it years ago).

Comment: @jww Not sure to be honest. I have fought with this problem for the longest time as well. RCDefaultApp finally did the trick for me.