# App to annotate images

Tags: applications

I know Preview can annotate images, but does anyone know which app is used to create the style of arrows in the following image?
[image]

(This appears in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/220496/251846, but the author has become inactive, it seems.)

Comment: Looks like https://evernote.com/intl/de/products/skitch

Comment: Confirmed - just tried and it is indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [Skitch](https://evernote.com/intl/en/products/skitch) which can be downloaded from the Evernote website as well as from the App Store. AFAIR it works without an Evernote account.

[image]