# File with no extension will be opened by TextEdit by default. How do I change that?

Tags: macos, textedit, file-extensions, bbedit

File with no extension will be opened by TextEdit by default. For example, in terminal run `open ~/.ssh/known_hosts` will open TextEdit to edit `known_hosts`

These files are normally just text file so I don't want to use TextEdit open them (e.g. I want to use BBEdit to open them) but because they have no extension I can't find an each way to change the default app to open them in one shot. Change them one by one is not workable.

So is there any way to change them in one shot?

[Replace Text Edit as the default text editor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123833/replace-text-edit-as-the-default-text-editor) does not work for me,

First, the highest two answers there said something like `duti -s com.sublimetext.4 public.plain-text all` but as @Seamus said in his updated answer  "The accepted answer may have been correct when it was written, but does not work for current (as of approximately Catalina vintage) systems because the UTI for a text file without a file extension is now apparently public.data". Besides I don't know how edit bbedit part, is it com.bbedit.13 （I use bbedit 13 or what else）?

Second, all the other 3rd-party apps are too old, at least 10 years old without any update.

Comment: Any unresolved aspects of this question? ICYI, I found a lot of useful information for further research from these sources: [1](https://eclecticlight.co/2022/12/24/how-does-macos-tell-the-type-of-a-file/); [2](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html); [3](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/07/05/identifying-file-types-utis-filename-extensions-and-another-free-app/); [4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers)

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to do it. Note that I've done limited testing of this on my macOS Ventura system - YMMV.

##### One Approach:

In `Terminal.app` enter the following command:

```shell
% defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist LSHandlers -array-add '{LSHandlerContentType=public.data;LSHandlerRoleAll=com.barebones.bbedit;}'
```

You will need to ***re-start*** your machine afterwards for this to take effect.

Alternatively, you may edit the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist` to add the following as the last `<dict>` element in the plist:

```
        .
        ..
        ...
        <dict>
            <key>LSHandlerContentType</key>
            <string>public.data</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
            <string>com.barebones.bbedit</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: "Other answers depend on 3rd-party apps which are either obsolete or ill-maintained." A Swift one: https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps

Comment: Is restarting the only way?

Comment: @Andy: good question.  Based on similar usages of `defaults` you ***may have*** a couple of alternatives to a re-start: 1) log out & logon; 2) run `killall Finder` from the Terminal.

Comment: I tried log out/on and relaunching Finder&Dock - no luck

Comment: @Andy: Have you tried a re-start? Sorry - it's been almost a year since this was posted. I do try hard to *test* everything I put in an answer, so it's also possible that a re-start was the only way I found to make it persistent.  ALSO: Just checked my system, and learned the file has been changed to a ***binary*** file in one of Apple's updates. Consequently, it is also possible that this no longer works!

Comment: It worked for me with restart but I would really like to avoid it somehow

Comment: @Andy: What version of macOS are you using for this task?

Comment: The latest 14.4

Comment: @Andy: And is the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist` on your system a plain-text file?

Answer (score 0):

The modern replacement for RCDefaultApp (the ancient prefs pane you're presumably referring to) is "SwiftDefaultApps"

https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps

For text files, you need to set the handlers for `public.plain-text` and `public.data` (the latter necessary for files with no extension, which are opened by default with TextEdit - yuck)