# How do I set the default app to open text files?

Tags: macos, finder, system-settings

I often find myself wanting to open a variety of text based files, that do not always have file extensions, and I'd like to use a different text editor from TextEdit and XCode. Is there an easy way to set it up so that my default text editing app is something I pick?

Comment: If they don't all have the same extension, and they don't all have the same creator code (which is a vanishing thing anyway), the OS has no easy way to determine that they are a "text" file.

Comment: @MarcWilson There was a default which if it was an unknown file type it would use a default app TextEdit. Setting this used to be a simple very simple dwrite - later more complex as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123833/replace-text-edit-as-the-default-text-editor?rq=1 but I don't know if this works still