# Make Sublime Text (or any other editor) default text editor on macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, text-editor

I like using Sublime Text as my text editor. The only issue is that whenever I have an unrecognized file type (which happens quite frequently), double clicking on it tries to open it in TextEdit, Xcode, or some other irrelevant application.

I know it's possible to change the default, text editor for a particular file type, but it typically involves the following steps:

1. Select the file
2. Press Command + I
3. Click Open With > Other
4. Chang "Enable" to "All Applications" (necessary to select ST)
5. Find "Sublime Text" in the list and select "Add"
6. Click on "Change All" to change this for all applications
7. Confirm the dialog box that will pop up

As can be seen, this is quite an arduous process which I would like to avoid doing every time I want to open a new file type in Sublime Text. Is there any easier way to go about doing this?

Sublime Text unfortunately does not have an option to assign it to common file types.

Comment: [RCDefaultApp is a Mac OS X 10.2 or higher preference pane that allows a user to set the default application used for various URL schemes, file extensions, file types, MIME types, and Uniform Type Identifiers (or UTIs; MacOS 10.4 only)](https://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/).

Comment: [Changing the default text editor on macOS](https://gomakethings.com/changing-the-default-text-editor-on-macos/) and the answer there is from [Ask Different as a duplicate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123833/replace-text-edit-as-the-default-text-editor/123834#123834) and also shows up in the [Related side bar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123833/replace-text-edit-as-the-default-text-editor?rq=1).